# No service for type has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, исключения, dependency-injection

Я полный новичок в ASP.NET и только разбираюсь с внедрением зависимостей, поэтому, скорее всего, моя ошибка очевидна, но все же я не понимаю, что именно не так. В моем проекте есть класс `StartCommand`, в котором используется некая реализация интерфейса `IUserService`. При попытке получить `UserService`, я получаю ошибку отсутствия регистрации сервиса, хотя, вроде как, я его зарегистрировал.

`Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlite(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICommand, StartCommand>();
```

`StartCommand`:

```
private readonly IUserService userService;

public StartCommand(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    userService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserService>(); <- Ошибка возникает тут
}
...
```

`IUserService`:

```
Task<AppUser?> GetUserAsync(Update update);
Task<bool> DeliteUserAsync(Update update);
Task<RegistratingStatus> RegistratingUserAsync(Update update);
```

`UserService`:

```
private readonly DataContext database;

public UserService(DataContext data)
{
    database = data;
}
...
```

Comment: Вы просите `UserService`, когда добавляете `.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();`, то есть `IUserService`. Другими словами, вы должны просить именно интерфейс, либо регистрировать тип класса без интерфейса. Ну и да, делать `public StartCommand(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)` не нужно, просите сразу нужный тип (`public StartCommand(IUserService userService)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользователь EvgeniyZ предложил рабочее решение в комментариях, вопрос закрыт.

---

Вы просите `UserService`, когда добавляете `.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();`, то есть `IUserService`. Другими словами, вы должны просить именно интерфейс, либо регистрировать тип класса без интерфейса. Ну и да, делать `public StartCommand(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)` не нужно, просите сразу нужный тип (`public StartCommand(IUserService userService)`).